# Back button in statusbar

Tags: codenameone

I don't need toolbar, title and all that. But I need back button (back button icon with a string back to Home). There is a status bar in iOS. Can I put back btn with icon and text in statusbar? I have seen it in fb. If I go to messenger from fb, back to facebook is in the status bar with time battery icons etc. Can we do that in codenameone?

Back button in status bar (not in title bar) in iOS

[image]

[image]

What I have done so far. I think this is similar to what have been suggested in the answer. It works in android but in iOS I want to keep the back btn in the status bar with time, battery icons etc.

```
t = new Toolbar();
t.setUIID("TitleAreaa");
f.setToolBar(t);
Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Button");
s.setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_MEDIUM));
Image backtoRTN = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ARROW_BACK, s);
back = new Command("Back to RTN", backtoRTN) {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        showForm("Main", this);
    }

};
back.putClientProperty("uiid", "BacktoRTN");
f.setBackCommand(back);
t.addCommandToLeftBar(back);
```

Answer (score 0):

The right thing to do here is something similar to what we do in [this demo](https://www.codenameone.com/demos-CleanModern.html)

[image]

Notice that the smiley is part of the UI and not part of the title...

The trick for doing this is simple override this method in your `Form`:

```
@Override
protected void initGlobalToolbar() {
    Toolbar tb = new Toolbar(true);
    tb.setUIID("Container");
    setToolbar(tb);
    getTitleArea().setUIID("Container");
}
```

That creates a toolbar that is layered (floats on top of the UI). Setting it to `Container` UIID makes it invisible.

Comment: I think you misunderstood a bit. I have updated the question with images. See if we can do that in cn1. Thankyou

Comment: That's not a back that "we" as application developers put. That's a back button the OS puts when it launches an application from another app.